# poi 4 Shift rows giving errror but working for poi 3

Tags: java, apache-poi-4

Hi I have recently migrated to poi 4 from poi 3. I am shifting some rows in a table and inserting new rows. In my sheet there are some tables below the table into which I am inserting rows and I am updating the references for those tables. This code was working for poi 3. I recently shifted to poi 4 and this code has started to corrupt the file. The trouble maker I suspect is the update reference part. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
sheet.shiftRows(firstEmptyRow, sheet.getLastRowNum(), iRowsToBeInserted, true, true);

    Row destrow = null;
    int finalRow = iRowsToBeInserted + firstEmptyRow - 1;

    for (int i = firstEmptyRow; i <= finalRow; i++) {
        destrow = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (destrow == null) {
            System.out.println("row at " + i + " is null : creating new");
            destrow = sheet.createRow(i);
        }
        for (int j = startColumn; j <= endColumn; j++) {
            Cell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(j);
            Cell NewCell = destrow.createCell(j);
            if (oldCell == null) {
                System.out.println("source cell is null!!!");
                oldCell = sourceRow.createCell(j);
            } else {
                System.out.println("old cell value " + parseCell(oldCell));
            }
            CellStyle newCellStyle = iWorkbook.createCellStyle();

            newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            if (oldCell.getCellStyle() != null && oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor() != null
                    && oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor() != null) {
                System.out.println("fill background color " + oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor()
                        + " fillb color color " + oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor().toString()
                        + " fill foreground color " + oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor()
                        + " fillc color color " + oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor().toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("either old cell cellstyle is null or its fill colors are null");
            }
            NewCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
            // If there is a cell comment, copy
            if (oldCell.getCellComment() != null) {
                NewCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());
            }

            // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
            if (oldCell.getHyperlink() != null) {
                NewCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());
            }
            NewCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());
        }
    }
    crEnd = new CellReference(crEnd.getSheetName(), finalRow, endColumn, crEnd.isRowAbsolute(), crEnd.isColAbsolute());
    final AreaReference newArea = new AreaReference(crStart, crEnd, iWorkbook.getSpreadsheetVersion());
    iTable.setArea(newArea);
    iTable.updateReferences();
    for (XSSFTable t : sheet.getTables()) {
        t.updateReferences();
        crStart = t.getStartCellReference();
        crEnd = t.getEndCellReference();
        AreaReference tableArea;
        System.out.println("Co-ordinates of table: " + t.getName() + " start x:y " + crStart.getRow() + ":"
                + crStart.getCol() + " end x:y " + crEnd.getRow() + ":" + crEnd.getCol());
        if (t.getName().equals(iTable.getName()) || crEnd.getRow() < newArea.getFirstCell().getRow()) {
            System.out.println("table is/before expanded table - continuing");
            continue;
        } else {
            System.out.println("table needs to be updated");
            CellReference crStartNew = new CellReference(crStart.getSheetName(), crStart.getRow() + iRowsToBeInserted, crStart.getCol(),crStart.isRowAbsolute(), crStart.isColAbsolute());
            CellReference crEndNew = new CellReference(crEnd.getSheetName(), crEnd.getRow() + iRowsToBeInserted, crEnd.getCol(), crEnd.isRowAbsolute(), crEnd.isColAbsolute());
            tableArea = new AreaReference(crStartNew, crEndNew, iWorkbook.getSpreadsheetVersion());
            AreaReference  arefArea = t.getArea();
            System.out.println(arefArea.toString());
            System.out.println(tableArea.toString());
            t.setArea(tableArea);
            t.updateReferences();
        }
    }
```

Comment: After running this code, I am able to observe that the file is corrupted and excel asks to repair the file. The tables below the modified table loose their format but the data is inserted correctly in the modified table.

Answer (score 0):

It is "known" bug. Unfortunately it is not resolved. There is a 
[workaround](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57423#c13)
to solve this problem

The most interesting snapshot is:

```
for (int nRow = nFirstDstRow; nRow <= nLastDstRow; ++nRow) {
            final XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(nRow);
            if (row != null) {
                String msg = "Row[rownum=" + row.getRowNum()
                        + "] contains cell(s) included in a multi-cell array formula. "
                        + "You cannot change part of an array.";
                for (Cell c : row) {
                    ((XSSFCell) c).updateCellReferencesForShifting(msg);
                }
            }
        }
```